# IAP fails after release, but no in development stage

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Here is the history of my app. 
In v1.0 I didn't have IAP.

In v2.0 I had IAP code, and it worked while I was developing. When v2.0 was released, I checked and run a non-testing device (an iPhone under my itunesconnect user name, but does not have provision file installed, so I take it as a non-relevant device) and I got error message, which of course was set up by myself. The error is for situation that the app could not connect to Apple or could not find IAP for the app. The error shows up quickly right after clicking buy IAP. This is as expected since no product ID is available. It doesn't need wait payment queue at all.

Then I checked itunesconnect and found the IAP probably not linked to the app, so I updated to v2.1 and added the IAP to my app in itunesconnect (no real code change, at least no IAP-related code changed), and IAP works fine finally in development stage in my testing iPad. Now v2.1 came out, but I still have the same problem as v2.0, that means IAP encounters error, most likely no IAP product ID found. At the time I'm typing, v2.1 has been released for 2 hours, and I still have quick error --- the product ID problem, most likely.

[edit]
BTW, there was a glitch between v2.0 and v2.1. When I noticed the IAP was not linked to my app, I did something too quick so that I cannot remember exactly. Basically the IAP was hung over there, I could modify it or submit it. After talking to Apple, I was told I need reject my binary of v2.1 and resubmit v2.1 along with the IAP. I don't know if this is related, but anyway I can buy IAP in development stage with my sandbox testing iPad.
[edit]

Any idea? Thanks.

BTW, the app is set to English default, but with Chinese/Spanish localization.

[edit]
One more thing, don't know if it's related. All v1.0, v2.0, and v2.1 versions are deployed to iOS 6 or later. When I was developing v2.1, I was trying to back to iOS 5 (via adopting so deprecated methods or constants). My app could run on iOS 5, but IAP wouldn't work iOS 5. Since IAP doesn't work, there's no point for me to go compatible with iOS 5, so I removed all deprecated methods and constants and went back to original v2.0 version and resubmitted with linked IAP to become v2.1.
For those who cares, here is my app. You're welcome to try. long press first page would get you to options page where you can try buy IAP --- no worry, there is supposed to be a confirmation dialog where you can cancel, even if my IAP works.
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/icalc24!/id566916783?mt=8
[edit]

One more edit:
OH yeah, it works now. I don't which step of the following make it work:
1, I delete my app and restart my iPhone again (and again, yes) and re-download
2, it's 4 hours now after v2.1 is approved.

Comment: In the iTunesConnect->"Manage In-App Purchases" section of your latest app version, what's the status of all your IAP products? Approved?

Comment: yes, it's approved， both my app and the IAP.

Comment: Are there any updated documents in the Contracts, Tax, and Banking section to sign?

Comment: I remember I signed again 2 or 3 weeks ago when Apple says there's something new need to sign. I just checked that page, and I didn't see any documents need signature.

Comment: In the apple dev center where you create the app, did you enable the IAP?

Comment: I remember this step, but I now go back to check, I couldn't find anything saying this. Did I miss anything here?

Comment: It's working now. I see buy IAP confirmation/cancel dialog now, I didn't try to buy it though. Not sure if I should waste two dollars to test it. Hoho.

Comment: I am getting strange issue. IAP executes 2nd time without asking for userid and password. And during this execution it asks for pwd later.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119960/issue-is-auto-renewable-subscription-sandbox-mode :(