# In-App Purchase not working in Apple Store but working in the sandbox

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am developing an iOS application with In-App Purchase (IAP). I have tested the IAP (in the sandbox environment) and it's working fine. Apple accepted the application and my IAP is ready for sale. But when users download the application and try to buy, they receive the alert **the product is not yet available**.

For information, I have two Apple accounts, one for the client and one for me. I have added the same productID in the two accounts. In my account it's just for testing and I have used the same productID for the release of the application with the client's account.

Do you think that the use of the same productID can cause this error in the Apple store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally it was a Bug from the Apple Store, after waiting (6 days) it's OK.

Answer (score 1):

how long did you wait after approval? My experience is that 4-hour of waiting, check it out here --- plus you can go thru a few things in the link to see if any of that was not properly set for your app.
[IAP fails after release, but no in development stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574037/iap-fails-after-release-but-no-in-development-stage)

Comment: This was my issue -- first release of our new app with IAP products worked fine in testflight/sandbox. Then when it released to the app store no IAP products were found. I was freaking out, testing everything. About 12h later IAP just started to work. Apparently apple's IAP update for the products takes longer to go through their servers than the release of the app itself