# How make sandbox environment in iphone

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I want to test IAP in sandbox environment.

How make **sandbox environment** in iPhone?

I have already developed IAP.
But I can't test it in sandbox environment.

I want to see below message in my iPhone.

**Sign-In Required [Environment: Sandbox]**

Comment: Log out of your iTunes account on your iOS device. Then run your development app on your iOS device. Attempt to make an in-app purchase. You will see the sandbox sign-in message.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually test the in-app purchasing in the sandbox environment, basically you'll need to set up an test user account in your iTunesConnect.

Check the apple documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html

You'll be able to find all the information related to In-App Purchasing, including sandbox testing.

Similar question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498005/ios-in-app-purchase-test-a-real-purchase-without-submitting-to-apple)

Comment: Very thanks your kind.      I want to see below message in my iphone.
Sign-In Required [Environment: Sandbox]

Comment: How can i see it in my iphone?